# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Mark]
[image: Andrew]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

### Update May 2016

The moderator team needed some extra hands, and [Chuck](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/9720/chuck) agreed to fill that role. Please welcome him to the team.

[image: Chuck]

---

### Update November 2017

We'd like to welcome, [Ben](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/110/ben) to the team. He has graciously stepped up to fill an empty moderator slot.

[image: Ben]

Additionally, we have a moderator who is stepping down after 4+ years in the role. Please thank [ThomasH](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/131/thomash) for the many years of work he has done on the site.

Comment: Awesome, congratulations to the three of you :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks (I think...) Adam.

So far this site has been pretty good at maintaining itself, so thanks everyone, and please keep it that way :)